# A "blackbox" function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, function, security, browser, encapsulation

Is there a way to create a "blackbox" function in a browser JavaScript environment, such that calling it does something but it's impossible from the outside world to step through what's going on inside?

To be precise, I'm looking for a way that's

1. Transparent algorithm-wise: The code itself is visible to anyone who sees the code.
2. Opaque execution-wise: While you can see the code, it's impossible for a user to step through each step in the function to inspect variables for each step.

I guess what I'm looking for is some sort of a way to create an atomic function which disallows any browser debugger based inspection, for security purposes.

Comment: nope...........

Answer (score 3):

As per my understanding, there is no way to hide the code from the debugger at the time of execution due to JavaScript being a scripting language, and being interpreted at runtime.

Unlike the compiled code, JavaScript's conversion to machine code is held off until the code is actually executes. That's why we defer exposing any sensitive information on the client-side.

And yes, obfuscation is possible through code minification, but still, the code can be interpreted by a user through a bit of hardwork.

Comment: Why would converting to machine code prevent someone from stepping through it and figuring out what it's doing. There's 1000s of blogs/articles doing exactly just that showing how they stepped through machine code to find an exploit.

Comment: @gman -- I didn't say anything related to stepping through. OP wanted to _disallow any browser debugger based inspection_, and that is not possible in this context.

Comment: I guess then I don't understand the relevance of "Unlike the compiled code, JavaScript's conversion to machine code is held off until the code is actually executes". which you claim is the reason "That's why we defer exposing any sensitive information on the client-side".  Implying that if the code was machine code it would somehow help prevent leaking sensitive info. It would not

Comment: @gman -- Agree to your point. Since OP wanted a solution _for security purposes_, my agenda was to point out that writing anything sensitive in JavaScript makes it easier for the attaker. I am not denying the fact that the machine code cannot be hacked through. :)